# Как сделать так, чтобы блок со стрелкой уходил вниз при сворачивании блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть контейнер, который хочу открывать, закрывать при клике по стрелке, причем при сворачивании блок с галкой опускается вниз и сама стрелка разворачивается на противоположную, но не могу понять почему `toggle` не срабатывает.
[ссылка на фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1326/)

```js
 $('#bottom-arrow').click(function() {
   $('#fix-bot').toggle('slow');
 });
```

```css
#fix-bot {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#fix-bot p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#bottom-arrow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 23px;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#bottom-arrow:before {
  pointer-events: all;
  content: "\f106";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="bottom-arrow"></div>
<div id="fix-bot">
  <p>Контейнер</p>
</div>
```

Comment: А где вы нашли метод `toggle`, который принимает **две функции** в качестве аргументов. Например, в [оф. документации](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) сказано, что если методу передано два аргумента, то первый -- длительность, а второй -- функция, которая будет вызвана по завершению анимации. Иными словами, ваш код работает ровно так, как должен. И `toggle` тут не причем

Comment: к тому же toggle уже сам по себе совершает отображение/сокрытие елемента. Поэтому дополнительно вызывать show и hide не надо

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev вот здесь - http://jquery-docs.ru/events/toggle/ (Переключается между двумя или более функциями, вызывающимися поочередно каждым следующим нажатием ЛКМ.) там и пример похожий - неправильно интерепретирую? добавил фидл - http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1325/

Comment: @Вася, эм... это ваше руководство противоречит официальной документации... либо я совсем уже не соображаю.

Comment: @Alexander Halimon просто не понимаю как при сворачивани блока контейнера опускать блок со стрелкой вниз, а после поднимать

Comment: @Вася, хотя такой [метод](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) даже был в jQuery. Однако он удален в версии 1.9. А ваше руководство пора сжечь, как протухшее =)

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev ок, свернуть-развернуть блок не проблема, а вот как его можно привязать к блоку со стрелкой, чтобы он мог опускать вниз, когда контейнера нет и всплывать наверх, когда есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве решения можно обернуть все в контейнер, с позицией fixed, тогда остальные элементы будут занимать нужные места. И в скрипте нужно будет просто показывать/скрывать абзац.

```js
$('#bottom-arrow').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
  $('#fix-bot').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}
#fix-bot {
  height: 50px;
}
#fix-bot p {
  color: #fff;
}
#bottom-arrow {
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 23px;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#bottom-arrow:before {
  pointer-events: all;
  content: "\f106";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  transition: transform linear 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}
#bottom-arrow.toggled:before {
  content: "\f107";
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="bottom">
  <div id="bottom-arrow"></div>
  <div id="fix-bot">
    <p>Контейнер</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: да, только осталось еще стрелку научить переворачиваться)

Comment: @Вася, ну так `this` - это блок со стрелкой, присвой ему класс и будет переворачиваться

Comment: @Вася, добавил в пример изменение значка

Comment: да, точно - отлично!

Comment: и еще вопрос- как сделать все тоже самое, но не по клику, а проведению пальцем по экрану смартфона?

Comment: @Вася, тут стоит смотреть в сторону touch событий по аналогии с перетаскиванием

Comment: т.е. на перетаскивание вешать блок? `$('#bottom-arrow').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {..}`

Comment: пробую через библиотеку `hammer.js`, но пока не сильно получается http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1348/