# Как на смартфонах раскрывать список не табом, а тапом (касанием) пальца?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, touch-event

[В предыдущем топике](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525317/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0/525357?noredirect=1#comment651732_525357) с вашей помощью реализовали функционал, который позволяет сворачивать-разворачивать блок при клике на стрелку. Теперь меня интересует вопрос: как сделать раскрывающийся список для мобильных устройств не по табу, а по свайпу пальцем вверх-вниз? Подключил для этого библиотеку [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) Вот, что набросал, но пока не получается

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById('bottom-arrow');
var hammertime = new Hammer(myElement);
hammertime.on('swipe', function(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
  $(this).toggleClass('toggled');
  $('#fix-bot').toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
}
#fix-bot {
  height: 50px;
}
#fix-bot p {
  color: #fff;
}
#bottom-arrow {
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: 23px;
  background: rgba(153, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
#bottom-arrow:before {
  pointer-events: all;
  content: "\f107";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 17px;
  transition: transform linear 0.5s;
  display: inline-block;
}
#bottom-arrow.toggled:before {
  content: "\f106";
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.5/hammer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="bottom">
  <div id="bottom-arrow"></div>
  <div id="fix-bot">
    <p>Контейнер</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю проблема в свойстве `pointer-events: none;` для `#bottom-arrow` по которому вы хотите делать `swipe`!

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk возможно, хорошая догадка, но почему-то здесь тап работает как клик http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1354/ а здесь свайп не работает никак http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1355/

Comment: Вам принципиально важна версия `Hammer.js`? Взял первый попавшийся пример с Docs и все работает http://jsfiddle.net/6ckv4xnn/. Только swipe горизонтальный!

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk хмм.. а вы в эмуляторе пробуете или на мобильнике? в смартфоне у меня и этот пример не срабатывает..

Comment: как на ноуте, так и на телефоне, пример с jsfiddle у меня работает.

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk на 3 проверял - не срабатывает.. а как он у вас работает - при тапе или свайпе?

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk да, точно! работает, но свайп горизонтальный - не сразу обратил внимание) а можно его как-то сделать вертикальным или нет?

Comment: По идеи, нужно задать свойство направления `mc.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });`, но что-то не работает. Ищите в доках!

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk а по-моему работает http://jsfiddle.net/6ckv4xnn/1/

Comment: Действительно, вот и отлично!

Comment: @Igor Tkachuk в тестовом да, но в рабочем почему-то ругается на `mc.get is not a function...`